# Avoid Maven complaints about mock objects without any @Test

Tags: java, maven, junit

Maven 3.x.x complains about my mock "TestPacket" class that I use for another real test:

```
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
```

How can I avoid Maven complaining about this?
I did this for now (in TestPacket):

```
@Test
public void workaround() {
}
```

But there should be another clean way...

Thank you for your time!

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of an JUnit issue than a maven one. If you don't want your TestPacket class to be treated as a JUnit test class by JUnit, annotate it (at the class level) with JUnit's `@Ignore` annotation

Comment: Please note that some people expect that an `@Ignore`-ed class is just temporarily disabled as `@Ignore` javadoc said: "Sometimes you want to temporarily disable a test or a group of tests." I often search for `@Ignore` in the code for disabled tests to fix them. Lot of false result could be disturbing. Furthermore this practice permanently increases the count of skipped tests in Surefire/Hudson reports.

Answer (score 3):

Exclude the [default `"**/Test*.java"` inclusion rule](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) in the configuration of the surefire plugin in the pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

A better solution is excluding only your `TestPacket` class.